# localhost is unable to load application centos server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, centos, nuxt.js

Trying to fire up a Laravel api and Nuxt app on the actual server by running

```
lets say server IP is - 10.66.22.41

npm run dev
php artisan serve --port=8001
```

This obviously worked on my local environment but since this is in the actual server and I am not too familiar with Centos, is there anything I should be doing different?

When I run `npm run serve` I get `http://localhost:3001/`
When I run `php artisan serve --port=8001` i get `http://127.0.0.1:8001`

dumb question:

How should I be accessing this on the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the artisan serve command, will keep the server running until you close the console, which will terminate the service! It is not an ideal setup... I would recommend that you install a webserver of some sort, and install laravel properly via composer. We cannot see how you installed NPM, or if you installed Apache? etc..

I would recommend to install centos webpanel for a starter:
http://centos-webpanel.com/

Then install composer https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-centos-7/

Then install laravel using: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#installing-laravel

This is your best way to manage and run laravel on centos properly (for beginners), if you have the money for it, you should buy CPanel (https://cpanel.net/pricing/) instead of Centos WebPanel, as it offers more flexibility and features.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

for Nuxt, added your script in package.json

```
  "scripts": {

    "dev:host": "nuxt --host 'IP-Address' --port 3001",
}
```

Run:

```
dev:host": "nuxt --host 'IP-Address' --port 3001
```

For Laravel:

```
 php artisan serve --host=IP-Address  --port=8001
```

Quick point though, What Khali should be the best practive but if you want to test or whatever you need to do , this is it.